# How to cut part of grepped value

Tags: linux, shell

I am running this command in a shell script:

```
user@nas:~$ lsblk -o NAME,PARTUUID | grep 9bf22f69-05
└─sdi1             9bf22f69-05                                                                        9bf22f69-05
```

How do I use `cut` in the command to only give me the first part (`sdi`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the *raw* output format of `lsblk` with `-r`:

```
$ lsblk -roNAME,PARTUUID 
NAME PARTUUID
sda 
sda1 f56e224a-94e0-401b-9081-b19d4f43e001
sda2 b3907cd2-ee93-4c49-870e-13e9f3ab9b31
sda4 b8e25594-6e1c-4f35-aff7-474971137144
sda5 514cfde6-f765-4cb3-bb26-8c5136f874a8
sda7 c5f8194a-0f87-43eb-9b92-d24d293bbc93
sda8 11ee6409-c750-4023-9cb5-bf7f435509ad
sda8 cdb29b03-d91b-4b19-89e2-634a56826015
```

Now it is simple to obtain the block devices identifier using `awk`:

```
$ lsblk -roNAME,PARTUUID | awk '/b3907cd2/{print $1}'
sda4
```

Comment: ah yes that worked, thanks: sudo lsblk -roNAME,PARTUUID | awk '/9bf22f69-05/{print $1}'

Comment: @johncs do you really need the `sudo`? If it works without it I suggest to drop it. Finally, a more precise matching of the second column might be a good idea: `lsblk -roNAME,PARTUUID | awk '$2 == "9bf22f69-05" {print $1}'`

Comment: good points @janos - i will look at not using sudo and updating it on column as well, thank you